# How to save data to REST API using a calculated model

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm building a UI in Google Appmaker to manage the Domain Shared Contacts API. I can read and display data from the API in appmaker using a calculated model, but I cannot save data back into the API.

I tried adding a form widget with the calculated model as a datasource, but this is a read / view only form. This is when i found out calculated data sources are always read-only in app maker.

I then created an SQL datasource and made an event that queries the Domain Shared Contact API which then creates records and saves them to the SQL Model. I was thinking about using the standard form widget and then in the events beforeSave, beforeDelete, etc to write the record to the API.

However this feels dirty to me, since now I have to keep the SQL model synchronized with the API, need to have an SQL server running, etc.

Does anyone have any tips on the best way to write data from a form in appmaker to a REST API? I can't be only one with this use case.

Comment: Presumably you are using the Directory Model? I would suggest using the URL Fetch Service with a post request described here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app in conjunction with the Directory API described here https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users. Of course keep in mind that if App Maker does not provide the proper credentials to the Admin SDK you may also have to include the proper oAuth flow for this. And finally, whichever user is trying to use this in AM also needs to have proper auth in the Admin SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write app script function for this. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app